# Extracting each unique data from a string

Tags: regex

I have been trying to set up REGEX extraction process for the following to no avail.

I have a set of date values in the formats to follow. I need to be able to extract these as unique individual dates.

If there is a single value, it is a standard simple format of mm/dd/yyyy. That one is easy.

If there are more than one date value, then it can be in a format as follows:
Feb 5, 12, 19, 26, Mar 4, 11 2016

I need to turn these into 02/05/2016, 02/12/2016, etc.

Eventually I will be inserting these dates into a database.

Am I going about this in the wrong way? Thanks for advice.

Comment: 1. Regex alone can't do this job, you'd most likely need a programming language. 2. I'd *parse* the input instead of regex'ing it 3. I [strongly encourage you](https://xkcd.com/1179/) to [always use a yyyy-mm-dd format](http://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/iso-date)

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. The data is raw from a feed. I understand it is not ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that there are no deviations or anomalies in the data that you're RegExing, the following RegEx can be applied with case-sensitivity set and allow you to access the information you need. With RegExs, it's important to "know your data" because this variable can greatly alter the construction of a RegEx -- the balance between specificity and clarity is important since RegExs can easily become unwieldy and cryptic.

Save the months as: `([A-Z][a-z][a-z])` // this can be your $1 variable (useful later)

Save the day values as: `\s*(?:([0-9]?[0-9]),\s)*` // $2 variable should work for access to this list of values

Save the year values as: `([0-9]{4,4})` // $3 variable should work for accessing these values NOTE: this only works for #### formatted dates by design although it can be altered to handle different formats; I'm just going off of the example you provided

Stringing it all together you get: `(?:([A-Z][a-z][a-z])\s*(?:([0-9]?[0-9]),\s)*)+([0-9]{4,4})`

You can then construct objects with these values so that you don't end up with a bunch of chaotic data. Let me know if I addressed you problem properly. If there's something that I missed or some additional functionality that you forgot to mention, I will be happy to assist.

Answer (score 1):

This will be complete spaghetti if you try to do it with one regex:

- You will have to hardcode the names of the months and the corresponding numbers somewhere.
- The year doesn't follow after the list of days of the month, rather after the list of all month names - month days this year.

However with a little help from a normal programming language you can still get a short and regex-centric solution. Here is a small Ruby snippet to show the general idea:

```
# this is the input
dates = "Feb 5, 12, 19, 26, Mar 4, 11 2016, Jul 5, 7, 19, 26, May 4, 11 2017"

# a hash with month name => month number
MONTHS = {
  'Jan' => '01',
  'Feb' => '02',
  'Mar' => '03',
  'Apr' => '04',
  'May' => '05',
  'Jun' => '06',
  'Jul' => '07',
  'Aug' => '08',
  'Sep' => '09',
  'Oct' => '10',
  'Nov' => '11',
  'Dec' => '12',
}

# match and extract three things:
#  month - the first found month name (three letters)
#  days  - list of days separated by commas and spaces for this month
#           for example 5, 12, 19, 26, 
#  year  - the first found year (four digits)
# ,? is because we don't have , after the last day of the year
while dates =~ /(\w{3}) ((?:\d\d?,? )+).*?(\d{4})/
  month, days, year = $1, $2, $3
  # to each day collate a date in the wanted format
  #  MONTHS[month] gets the month number from the hash above
  #  sprintf simply makes sure that one digit days will have a leading 0
  dates_this_month = days.split(/,? /).map do |day|
    "#{MONTHS[month]}/#{sprintf('%02d', day)}/#{year}"
  end.join ', '
  # substitute the dates for this month with the new format
  dates.sub! "#{month} #{days}", "#{dates_this_month}, "
end

# remove leftover years
dates.gsub! /, \d{4}/, ''
```

Now `dates` is in the desired format.